# Serilog logger is duplicating each log line

Tags: c#, serilog

I am experimenting with the new Azure v12 SDK and using Serilog to log items to the console (Its a .Net 5 console application)

Every Log.Logger line is duplicating itself on the console BUT not in the log file. I am trying to figure out why this is happening.

Console screenshot
[image: Console Logging]

Log file screenshot
[image: Log file logging]

Here is my Serilog setup in Program.cs

```
private static IHost AppStartup(string logFilepath)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        ConfigSetup(builder);

        // defining Serilog configs
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Build())
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .WriteTo.Seq("https://localhost:5341/")
            .WriteTo.File(logFilepath, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
            .CreateLogger();

        // Initiated the dependency injection container 
        var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureServices((context, services) => {
                services.AddLogging(m => m.AddSerilog(Log.Logger));
                services.AddTransient<IAzureService, AzureService.AzureService>();
                services.AddTransient<BlobServiceManager>();
            }).Build();
        //this line is duplicating as well!
        Log.Logger.Information($"{DateTime.Now}: Serilog logger created for LoadCurrencyDataAndProcess");
        return host;
    }
```

Here is the code in the method. (I have stepped through the code and am CERTAIN when the Log.Logger line executes, it is double printing in the console, the code ISN'T running twice)

```
public void ListContainers(BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient)
{
    try
    {
        Log.Logger.Information($"From containers collection");
        var containers = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainers();
           
        foreach (var container in containers)
        {
        //Also tried just Log.Information here, it produced same result
            Log.Logger.Information($"Container name: {container.Name}");
        }
    }
    catch (RequestFailedException e)
    {
        Log.Logger.Error($"{DateTime.Now}: An error occurred trying to retrieve containers from {_service.StorageClient.AccountName} with error message {e.Message}");
           
    }
}
```

Here is my configuration for Serilog in appsettings.json

```
 "Serilog": {
"Using": [],
"MinimumLevel": {
  "Default": "Information",
  "Override": {
    "Microsoft": "Warning",
    "System": "Warning"
  }
},
"Enrich": [ "FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithProcessId", "WithThreadId" ],
"WriteTo": [
  { "Name": "Console" },
  {
    "Name": "ApplicationInsights",
    "Args": {
      "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information",
      "telemetryConverter": "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters.TraceTelemetryConverter, Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights"
    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "File",
    "Args": {
      "path": "C:\\Users\\Logs\\CurrencyData\\currencydataprocessingtotablestorage.txt",
      "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:G} :: Message:=={Message}{NewLine:1} Exception:=={Exception:1}"
    }
  },
  {
    "Name": "Seq",
    "Args": {
      "serverUrl": "https://localhost:5341/"
      //or 8081
     }
   }
 ]
}
```

Its not a major issue, I am just trying to understand why it is happening to ensure my logging is setup correctly. (I'm new to using Serilog)

Comment: Could you please provide the configuration file (the serilog part of it)?

Comment: Added to the post

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You both specified sinks in your `LoggerConfiguration` and your `appsettings.json`:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Build())
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .WriteTo.Seq("https://localhost:5341/")
    .WriteTo.File(logFilepath, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
    .CreateLogger();
```

---

```
"WriteTo": [
  { "Name": "Console" },
  {
    ...
  },
  {
    "Name": "File",
    ...
  },
  {
    "Name": "Seq",
    ...
  }
 ]
```

Sinks shold be configured only in one place. I recommend to remove all `WriteTo` statements and only use the configuration file because it is more flexible and you can remove sinks later in production use through configuration if you want.

So just remove these lines:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Build())
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    //.WriteTo.Console()
    //.WriteTo.Seq("https://localhost:5341/")
    //.WriteTo.File(logFilepath, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
    .CreateLogger();
```

Comment: What is the difference between using Log.Information or Log.Logger.Information?

Comment: There is no difference in these both calls. `Log.Information()` is just a wrapper call for `Log.Logger.Information()`. So you can use `Log.Information()` because it is shorter.